# Possible to return a collection of values when a single value parameter is chosen in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

In a SSRS report, is it possible to return a collection of values when a single value parameter is chosen?

For example, I want to have a parameter `Team`, with options: "Cardinals, Orioles, Blue Jays".

When a team is selected, I want to return the members of the selected team, so I can do something like

```
Select Runs
From Baseball.Data
WHERE Player IN (@Team)
```

Is this possible in Reporting Services or is there a better technique?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to use two parameters, one for let users to select the team. Other parameter to pass the players of the team to the query. I'd use a `LookupSet()` function to get the players. If you need further help provide the table structure where Team and Players are mapped.

Comment: I just want to hard code the team player mapping in the report.  They will never change and I don't have a table with them.   Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the Cardinals players? How can you identify it in the  Baseball.Data table since I supposed Player is the name of the player not the team. Do you have a Team column in the Baseball.Data table?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244656/using-ssrs-report-to-pass-in-a-param-value-the-is-a-csv-list-to-sql-dataset

Comment: There is no team column in the table.  I want to hardcode the team to player mapping in the report and, when a team is chosen as a parameter, return the list of players belonging to the selected team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another parameter `@Players` and set it as multivalued parameter and internal. Use this expression to populate the parameter.

```
=Switch(
Parameters!Team.Value="Cardinals",split("CardinaPlayer1,CardinalPlayer2,CardinalPlayer3",","),
Parameters!Team.Value="Orioles",split("OriolesPlayer1,OriolesPlayer2,OriolesPlayer3",","),
Parameters!Team.Value="Blue Jays",split("BlueJaysPlayer1,BlueJaysPlayer2,BlueJaysPlayer3",",")
)
```

> I am supposing @Team is not a multivalue parameter. Replace
>   CardinalPlayerX, OriolesPlayerX, etc. by the actual name of players.

Now in the query just use the `@Players` parameter:

```
Select Runs
From Baseball.Data
WHERE Player IN (@Players)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is really close, but only returns the first player from each list.  What seems to work (but seems even hackier) is using a switch for each default value of the players parameter.  For example, 
    Value 1=Switch(
    Parameters!Team.Value="Cardinals","CardinaPlayer1",
    Parameters!Team.Value="Orioles","OriolesPlayer1",
    Parameters!Team.Value="Blue Jays","BlueJaysPlayer1"
    ) 

And then each subsequent value would include a similar switch statement.  Thanks.

Comment: Note split functions returns an array with the players (in my case 3). It necessary to determine if the parameter or the query are returning only one player. Create textbox and use this expression in the report. =join(Parameters!Players.Value,",") preview the report to see if there is only one player in the parameter.

Comment: Single Value.  It is ok.  I can just do it my hacky way and call it a day.  Thanks for the help.